# Send downstream messages from java backend using FCM

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging

I am sending downstream messages to 30000 users from java backend using FCM.

Question is:

1. How long will it take for the message to be received by 30000 users?
2. Can we send 30000 messages simultaneously or do we need to create 30 batches comprising of 1000 users each?

Any appropriate answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's not possible to know for sure.  The devices might receive the message instantly, or it may take days if they're not connected. Each device will be different.
2. There is a limit of 1000 tokens per batch, according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json).  So you will have to split it up.